# In gimp : how to save the different layers of a design in separate files/images?

Tags: gimp, layers

I wonder if there's a way in gimp to make the different layers of a design into separate image files without having to save the image each time. I hope this is clear. I use layers also as variations on the theme and for my latest projects i d like to put all those variations  individually in a new context.

Comment: i guess you have to get a plugin for saving layers in separate file

Answer (score 7):

The link to the script in the post pointed by Pankaj was broken, so I wrote my own "save layers" script in Python. To use the script, save the following script to your plug-in directory (e.g. `~/.gimp-x.x/plug-ins/save_all_layers.py`), and if on Linux/Mac give the script the execute permission bit (e.g. `chmod +x ~/.gimp-x.x/plug-ins/save_all_layers.py`), then restart GIMP.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *
from os.path import join

def save_all_layers(image, __unused_drawable, directory, name_pattern):
    for layer in image.layers:
        filename = join(directory, name_pattern % layer.name)
        raw_filename = name_pattern % layer.name
        pdb.gimp_file_save(image, layer, filename, raw_filename)

register(
    "python_fu_save_all_layers",
    "Save all layers into separate files",
    "Save all layers into separate files",
    "Lie Ryan",
    "Lie Ryan",
    "2012",
    "<Image>/File/Save layers as images...",
    "*",
    [
        (PF_DIRNAME, "directory", "Directory to put the images on", "/"),
        (PF_STRING, "name_pattern", "Pattern for file name, %s will be replaced with layer name", "%s.png"),
    ],
    [],
    save_all_layers
)

main()
```

Now you can just go to `File > Save layers as images` to, well, save layers as images.

Alternatively, if you do not fancy restarting GIMP or if you do not want to install the plugin permanently, then copy-paste the following function into the Python-fu console:

```
def save_all_layers(image, directory, name_pattern):
    for layer in image.layers:
        filename = join(directory, name_pattern % layer.name)
        raw_filename = name_pattern % layer.name
        pdb.gimp_file_save(image, layer, filename, raw_filename)
```

and use it as such:

```
>>> # first, find the image object
>>> gimp.image_list()
[<gimp.Image 'Untitled'>, <gimp.Image 'slice_5.xcf'>]
>>> # I want to edit slice_5.xcf, so I select that image
>>> img = gimp.image_list()[1]
>>> # double check that you got the correct image
>>> img
<gimp.Image 'slice_5.xcf'>
>>> # and finally call the function, the %s will be replaced by layer names
>>> save_all_layers(img, "/path/to/save/directory/", "image_%s.png")
```

Comment: works perfectly well, thanks!  exports EVERYTHING, including hidden layers and transparency.  UPVOTED! :)

Comment: Works like magic, one catch though, you should name the file exactly as he said 'save_all_layers.py' or it wont work

Answer (score 2):

Just as a small update to the great @Lie Ryan's answer. There can be problems with layers which names contain special characters (like '/'), so `save_all_layers` function could be adjusted to handle this (based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename-in-python)).

```
from os.path import join
import string

valid_chars = "-_.() %s%s" % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits)

def make_safe(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c in valid_chars)

def save_all_layers(image, directory, name_pattern):
    for layer in image.layers:
        filename = join(directory, make_safe(name_pattern % layer.name))
        raw_filename = make_safe(name_pattern % layer.name)
        pdb.gimp_file_save(image, layer, filename, raw_filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

wherever i know you have to install a script for doing the same :

the link is given below check this and read this carefully..

http://registry.gimp.org/node/15617

@ all 
i am a newbie  to gimp so might be less knowledge :(

if i am wrong than please correct me

Thanks

Comment: Within that page is indeed a link to a script which is intended to save multiple layers separately.